# Upgraded from Win XP to Win 7, now can't run my SAS scripts dealing with MySQL databases

Tags: mysql, windows-7, windows-xp, sas

my SAS scripts worked fine when I was in XP, but now that I've upgraded to Windows 7, my access to MySQL has been impaired. I am sure that MySQL is running. If I open a browser then I can send commands.... The issue is with the SAS software itself. Has anyone else had this issue? Know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Brian, can you provide some more details, such as

- The script you're running
- SAS log output, including the specific error message(s) you're getting
- Whether you're in a client/server situation or have SAS running on your Win7 machine
- Is MySQL running on your local machine? Can you look at the open connections via MySQL admin console?

Given what you've described, it's possible you've not only upgraded from XP to Win7 but also from SAS9.1.3 to SAS9.2. Is this correct?  If so, has SAS/ACCESS to MySQL been installed correctly? You can find out by submitting

```
proc setinit;run;
```